# find all the matches for unicodes in a string in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

```
import re

b="united thats weak. See ya "
print b.decode('utf-8')  #output: u'united thats weak. See ya \U0001f44b'

print re.findall(r'[\U0001f600-\U0001f650]',b.decode('utf-8'),flags=re.U) # output: [u'S']
```

How to get a output `\U0001f44b`.

Emojis that I need to handle are

```
_❤️_____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Does it mean you need to match just some emojis?

Comment: yes...i was trying to do it...but somehow not able to write a accurate pattern

Comment: can you update your question with all those emojis that you want to match? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Qubad....i just need a way to use regex in handling the emojis...its not more about a particular emoji. Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 2):

Searching for a unicode range works exactly the same as searching for any sort of character range. But, you'll need to represent the strings correctly. Here is a working example:

```
#coding: utf-8
import re

b=u"united thats weak. See ya  "
assert re.findall(u'[\U0001f600-\U0001f650]',b) == [u'']
assert re.findall(ur'[-]',b) == [u'']
```

Notes:

- You need `#coding: utf-8` or similar on the first or second line of your program.
- In your example, the emoji that you used, U-1f44b is not in the range U-1f600 to U-1f650. In my example, I used one that is.
- If you want to use `\U` to include a unicode character, you can't use the raw string prefix (`r''`).
- But if you use the characters themselves (instead of `\U` escapes), then you can use the raw string prefix.
- You need to ensure that both the pattern and the input string are unicode strings. Neither of them may be UTF8-encoded strings.
- But you don't need the `re.U` flag unless your pattern includes `\s`, `\w`, or similar.